# is_numeric function is giving unexpected results

Tags: php, isnumeric

I wrote the following php code,

```
<?php
 $k ="123e5";
if(is_numeric($k)){
    echo "is number";
}
else{
    echo "is not a number";
}
?>
```

the expected out put is  **"is not a number"** because e is present in the string. But I got the output **"is number"**. why is that happens? and please help me to find the solution.

Comment: so `e` is an exponent?

Comment: Indeed `123e5` is a number. See documentation: http://fi1.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: You could try `ctype_digit()` instead if you want to check for digits

Comment: in my problem "e" is not exponent. but I think is_numeric is treated as exponent.

Comment: Should it accept floating point numbers, e.g. "123.45"?

Comment: ctype_digit() is worked for my problem thanks @shatheesh and all others

Comment: possible duplicate of [is\_numeric, intval, ctype\_\_digit.. can you rely on them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462427/is-numeric-intval-ctype-digit-can-you-rely-on-them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ctype_digit() to check for numeric character(s)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php

```
<?php

$numeric_string = '42';
$integer        = 42;

ctype_digit($numeric_string);  // true
ctype_digit($integer);         // false (ASCII 42 is the * character)

is_numeric($numeric_string);   // true
is_numeric($integer);          // true
?>
```

Comment: Just don't forget that neither `.` nor `-` are digits.

Answer (score 4):

as per doc of [is_numeric](https://www.php.net/is_numeric):

> Numeric strings consist of optional sign, any number of digits,
> optional decimal part and optional exponential part. Thus +0123.45e6
> is a valid numeric value. Hexadecimal (e.g. 0xf4c3b00c), Binary (e.g.
> 0b10100111001), Octal (e.g. 0777) notation is allowed too but only
> without sign, decimal and exponential part.

so it is given right output.

I think you are looking for [integer only](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php). use `is_int()` then.

Comment: can u suggest a solution for my problem??

Comment: so, what do you want ?

Comment: `is_int()` won't work on a string, it will always be `false`.

Comment: need to type casting if you want to use is_int()

Comment: Casting to int will make `is_int()` always return `true`, ergo a useless operation :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP's built in filter functions to validate user input. Please have a look at the following handbook pages: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php